# How do I link drush to my drupal site thats hosted via localhost?

Tags: 7, drush

I have installed drush via terminal, but how do I link it to my 2 local drupal sites? When I do drush status I get this:

PHP configuration      :  /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini 
 PHP OS                 :  Linux
 Drush script           :  /usr/local/bin/drush
 Drush version          :  8.1.2
 Drush temp directory   :  /tmp
 Drush configuration    :
 Drush alias files      :

So how do I now link the drush to my two virtual host drupal sites? I looked online for a tutorial or guide, but I don't quite understand the ones I found on how to link them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to tell Drush which Drupal site you would like it to operate on.

1. Run Drush from the directory that contains the Drupal site's settings.php file.

   `$ cd /path/to/drupal_root/sites/default
   $ drush status`
2. Pass `--root` and `--uri` options that identify the site:

   `$ drush --root=/path/to/drupal_root --uri=http://mysite.dev status`
3. Create a site alias, and use that

   `$ drush @mysite status`

   In order to use the last option, you must define the `mysite` alias as described in the [example aliases file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/drush-ops/drush/master/examples/example.aliases.drushrc.php).

**UPDATE:**

The --uri option is used (a) to select which settings.php to use, and (b) to set the $_SERVER superglobal. If your settings.php file is in the `default` directory, then --uri is not necessary to bootstrap. However, some modules will expect the URI to be set up correctly; in some instances, you will not get the correct results if this setting is omitted.

Comment: Isn't moving to Drupal root enough?

Comment: Second option (uri) is not required to bootstrap Drupal.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I just went to my directory www/var/*nameofsitefolder* and right clicked and selected "open terminal from here", and that put me in "master mode" on the terminal and I was able to run Drush commands. Thanks ^_^